# Vue.js: how to make transition-group to trigger only once?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this Vue `transition-group` below. It works properly, but the problem is, when any element in the loop updates (`hash` changes, which is used for key), the transition group triggers the animation for that updated element (every time it updates).

I need it to only animate the elements once, when they are added to the `items` array (the elements are added with `items.unshift(newItem)`)

```html
<transition name="notification-transition">
  <custom-component
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="'item-' + item.hash"
  ></custom-component>
</transition>
```

```css
.notification-transition-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.notification-transition-leave-active {
  transition: all 0s ease;
}

.notification-transition-enter,
.notification-transition-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(256px);
}
```

Vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) mention that it runs "when items are inserted, updated, or removed from the DOM" but doesn't say anything about how to limit it to just the `inserted` and `removed` event.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It re-triggers transition because the property `item.hash`, which is used for key, changes. I have to use some static key property, that doesn't change

```html
<transition name="notification-transition">
  <custom-component
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="'item-' + item.staticHash"
  ></custom-component>
</transition>
```